# I don't quite understand this algorithm on queue

Tags: c++

Here's the queue using array implementation in Robert Sedgewick's book:

```
class QUEUE {
private:
    int* q;
    int N;
    int head;
    int tail;
public:
    QUEUE(int maxN) {
        q = new int[maxN + 1];
        N = maxN + 1; head = N; tail = 0;
    }
    int empty() const {
        return head % N == tail;
    }
    void put(int item) {
        q[tail++] = item; tail = tail % N;
    }
    int get() {
        head = head % N; return q[head++];
    }
};
```

My concern is about the `get()` method.
Consider the size to be 10;
According to the code, initially, the index of head = 11 and index of tail  = 0.

Now, add an element, say 1. So, 1 is placed in the index position 0 and the tail position is incremented to 1.
Now add another say 5. 5 is at index pos 1 and the tail now is index 2.

Now use the get() function, which does: `return q[head++];` which is to return the element at head and then increment the head but BOOOOOM!!!!! The head is index no 11 as we have just seen and it has no value stored in it and this must be a huge error. But, this code is correct as it's Robert Sedgewick and we are the one's mistaken. What's going on guys? :(

Comment: Note the `head = head % N` in the get method

Comment: Did you miss the whole `head = head % N` in your analysis?

Comment: Code is not guaranteed correct because it came from a book. If this is straight from the book, I'm a bit surprised as it's not following good practices. All caps names are by convention macros. Manual use of new. Use of int instead of size_t.

Comment: Agreed with @NeilKirk; the number of bad practices in this example alone is appalling. I would find a different book.

Comment: I deliberately didn't mention it as all it does is implement the circular array and has no other implications, right?

Comment: I know that book is really annoying but it's the book my instructor has chosen as the reference.

Comment: Ok, if you were to print out all the elements without modifying the queue, how would you do it?

Comment: Lol. I'm curious whether the people turfing Sedgewick's book(s) know anything about it, or him. The guy is a f'ing *legend*. His books aren't about writing perfect mission-critical code; they're about algorithms. Like most PhDs, while his ideas are brilliant, his code is crap. A common theme, unfortunately. If you're using this book to learn how to *code*, you likely have the wrong book (maybe something from Meyers would better suit that task).

Comment: `without modifying the queue` - you can't. You'd have to make a second, temporary, queue, `get()`, print, and put onto the temp queue all of the elements from the first queue, until it is empty. Then you'd have to recreate the initial state of the first queue by `get()`ing the temp queue's elements and `put()`ing them back on the first queue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out the `

```
head = head % n; // this mean head is now the remainder of the division 
                 // between head and N`
```

It means head is no longer 10;

```
head = 11 % 11 
which is 0 as the remainder of this division is zero.
Therefore, head = 0;
```

Then when you return q[head++], you are returning q[0] and then you are setting head to 1.

Comment: So, what is the implication on the get method?

Comment: Head, instead of being 11 is now 1 - the "%n" takes division, modulo n.

Comment: It means head is no longer 10; head = 11 % 11 which is 0 as the remainder of this division is zero. Then when you return q[head++], you are returning q[1]

Comment: You are actually returning `q[0]`.  Post increment returns the value before of the variable as it is before it gets incremented.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a queue with size 10 then head equals 10.  In get we use

```
head = head % N;
head = 10   % 10
head = 0
```

So head is 0 and then we increment it to 1.